# memory profiler for ironpython

Tags: ironpython, memory-management

I've downloaded Python Memory Validator and am trying to install Heapy to try to get a profile for my ironpython application.

So far PMV seems to choke for some reason with the message: `Failure injecting into executable image using CreateProcess()`

This seems to be an issue integrating ironpython with PMV.

Can anyone provide any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the very helpful Stephen Kellet:

```
IronPython uses .Net technology.
Thus your Python program is really a .Net program.

Therefore you should be using your program with .Net Memory Validator.
http://www.softwareverify.com/dotNet/memory/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Python Memory Validator is a commercial product, I'd ask the creator.